# Binary search on a sorted list of E(startTime,endTime) to find all E's matched by a given time range (t1,t2)

Tags: java, algorithm

I have `Event` objects as follows,

```
public class Event {
   String name;
   int startTime; // minutes since midnight, e.g 4:15am = 255
   int endTime;   // minutes since midnight, e.g.6:30am = 390
   // + getters/setters
}
```

They are sorted by startTime ASC,

```
events.sort(Comparator.comparing(Event::getStartTime));
```

Events can overlap in any way.

I need to obtain a List of all Events matching (**incl. partially**) a particular range `t1,t2` (also ints for minutes since midnight).

```
List<Event> eventsMatching = findMatching(t1, t2); // e.g. between 200,205
```

I don't want to go through the whole list and check `e.getStartTime() <= t1 && e.getEndTime() >= t2`. Since the list is sorted, I should be able to use `Collections.binarySearch()` in some way. But normally, a binary search finds the exact object you're looking for: `int position = Collections.binarySearch(events, key)`. Is there some way to find matching ranges quickly using a binary search?

Comment: Not at all, it could be overlapping

Comment: OK, I updated the post.

Comment: whats is the type of events?

Comment: @JawadElFou What do you mean "what is the type"? The `Event` class is its own type, as shown in code in Question.

Comment: I mean events with an s. Is it an List, a map ...?

Comment: How many range elements are you dealing with?

Comment: What do you mean by "matching a particular range"? Do you mean the start and end of the event are exactly the same as the start and end of the target range? Or do you mean to look for events  that overlap with at least part of that target range? Or do you mean events that are contained within that range (not exceeding either end of target range)? Your code `e.getStartTime() <= t1 && e.getEndTime() >= t2` means "find only events that entirely enclose the target range". Is that really what you want? So events overlapping target range would be excluded.

Comment: Based on some experimentation, you would need to do two binary searches, the first to find the start index (start time) and the second to find the end index (end time).  From this, you could create a `subList`.  However, I'd probably be tempt to just get the first index and the loop over that till I get the last matching item

Comment: @BasilBourque It can be a partial match. I updated the post. Therefore, E(100,200) will match `t1=150,t2=250`.

Comment: Since they are sorted you can try to find the first occurence of the starttime that meat your condition, then you check the endtime for the subsequent elements.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The events can overlap in any way. So I don't see how one could do a binary search for the end-time. But perhaps I'm not thinking straight.

Comment: @MadProgrammer it is not guaranteed that the time he is looking for exist in the events thus he can't use a binary search. ex 0 1 2  4 5 if he needs to find everything that is greater than 3 how a binary search can help?

Comment: You really need to state very clearly and very specifically your criteria. Your example code seems to contradict your last comment. The criteria determines the correct Answer.  But as written the Question is unclear. I am voting to close for that reason.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, I agree, so I'm not looking for an exact match - but personally, just loop over the bloody list and stop over thinking the bloody problem :/

Comment: @MadProgrammer The problem is that the matching criteria have not been stated clearly. So it might be that an event with an earlier start whose end date is far enough out might count as a match, yet would be ignored if we used a binary search based on start. As I said, I'm voting to close this Question as unclear. We are working much too hard at guessing what the OP really wants.

Comment: @BasilBourque maybe you are overthinking what OP wants

Comment: @JawadElFou We have OP's comment that contradict's the logic of the example query code. So, no, I don't think I'm overthinking it. The OP is underthinking it.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary search will not help you much, because you're not searching for a single equality-based match, but rather a *range* of results that can be ordered, but not in a way that's much help to quickly finding matches.

Unless you're dealing with a great many range elements (1000's), a linear (ie O(n)) process would work OK.

To speed things up, sort by start date beforehand, so your iteration over the list would be able to exit early when you encounter an element whose start date is after the target.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check for all events that meet `e.startTime <= t1`.

```
record Event(String name, int startTime, int endTime) {}
List<Event> list = Arrays.asList(
    new Event("a", 2, 3), new Event("b", 3, 4),
    new Event("c", 0, 1), new Event("d", 4, 5));
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Event::startTime));
System.out.println("sorted:   " + list);
int t1 = 2, t2 = 3;
List<Event> filtered = list.stream()
    .takeWhile(e -> e.startTime() <= t1)
    .peek(e -> System.out.println("checked:  " + e))
    .filter(e -> e.endTime() >= t2)
    .toList();
System.out.println("filtered: " + filtered);
```

output:

```
sorted:   [Event[name=c, startTime=0, endTime=1], Event[name=a, startTime=2, endTime=3], Event[name=b, startTime=3, endTime=4], Event[name=d, startTime=4, endTime=5]]
checked:  Event[name=c, startTime=0, endTime=1]
checked:  Event[name=a, startTime=2, endTime=3]
filtered: [Event[name=a, startTime=2, endTime=3]]
```

Comment: But actually, this will not include partial matches. An event can start later than `t1` but still be partially included.

Answer (score 1):

You should browse the list and stop when an item is not in range. In terms of complexity, it's the best you can do.